# VueJs child component prop change doesn't rerender it

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to make a dropdown where user can choose an option and will compose an API-query and the child component will send this query, get a response and shows the result. But for some reason choosing an option doesn't trigger rerendering the child component and showing filtered results.

Parent component (filtering dropdown):

```html
<template>
<div style="margin:1rem; width:13rem">
  <select name="cars_id" v-model="api_url" class="form-select form-control">
        <option>---- Bedrooms ----</option>
        <option value="api/v1/houses?filter[bedrooms]=3">3</option>
        <option value="api/v1/houses?filter[bedrooms]=4">4</option>
        <option value="api/v1/houses?filter[bedrooms]=5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<HouseList :api_url="api_url"/>
<p>{{ api_url }}</p>
</template>
 
<script>
import HouseList from './HouseList.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    HouseList
  },
  data() {
      return {
        api_url: "api/v1/houses"
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

Child component:

```html
<template>
  <div v-for="house in houses" :key="house.id">
    <div class="card-header">{{ house.name }}</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Price: {{ house.price }}</h4><hr>
      <div style="float:left;font-size: 0.9rem;">Bedrooms: {{ house.bedrooms }}<br>Bathrooms: {{ house.bathrooms }}</div>
      <div style="float:right; text-align: right;font-size: 0.9rem;">Storeys: {{ house.storeys }}<br>Garages: {{ house.garages }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {

  props: [
    'api_url'
  ],
  data() {
    return {
      houses: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios.get(this.api_url)
      .then(res => {
        this.houses = res.data;
        console.log(this.houses)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
         // Manage errors if found any
      })
  }
};
</script>
```

It only displays result of a request to "api/v1/houses" and never changes it after user choose something in a dropdown (how it is supposed to)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at the moment, your child component loads data only during the `mounted` hook:

```
  mounted() {
    axios.get(this.api_url)
      ...
  }
```

Later changes to `api_url` have no effect.

To change it, replace the hook with a [`watcher`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) on `api_url`:

```
watch: {
  api_url: {
    handler(){
      axios.get(this.api_url)
      ...
    },
    immediate: true
  }
}
```

Now a change to `api_url` will trigger a reload.